# IDE (IntelliJ/Eclipse) não roda o projeto em java

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jdk, intellij

Quando clico em 'run' em ambos os IDEs, não é encontrado a classe com quem quero trabalhar, então não é compilado. Atualizei o jdk e o intelliJ, mas continua a mesma coisa. O intelliJ não retorna erro, diferente do eclipse. Não sei o que fazer.
Segue print de um exemplo de hello world que não roda
O código no IntelliJ:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp3qD.png)
Quando clico em RUN, o que aparece:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ijxk.png)

Me disseram para ir em project structure e fiz isso, mas não sei se fiz certo:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4bff.png)

O código no eclipse :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgEu2.png)
O erro que retorna:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yljpe.png)

não sei o que fazer

Tentei atualizar a JDK, tentei manualmente como mostrei antes, mas não consegui ter resultado algum.

Comment: Experimente utilizar o classe pré-gerada Main ao invés de criar outra

Answer (score 0):

Para rodar um main no eclipse, basta apertar com botão direito dentro do metodo ir em 'Run as' e depois ir em 'java application'
[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF90q.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).